# VBA Excel for each loop issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that is supposed to loop through a column of break times and a column of staff times.  If the staff time is between 8:28 and 8:58, then if the break time is over 61 minutes, the cell should switch color.  Likewise, if the staff time is over 8:58, if the break time is over 91 minutes, the cell should switch color.  Right now, neither is happening, as something is obviously missing in the code.

```
    Dim ttlBr As Range, stfTm As Range
    Dim StfTm900 As Double, StfTm830 As Double, ttlBrTm900 As Double, ttlBrTm830 As Double
    StfTm900 = TimeValue("08:58:00")
    StfTm830 = TimeValue("08:28:00")
    ttlBrTm900 = TimeValue("01:31:00")
    ttlBrTm830 = TimeValue("01:01:00")
    For Each ttlBr In Range("T2:T7")
        For Each stfTm In Range("H2:H7")
            If stfTm > StfTm830 And stfTm < StfTm900 Then
                If ttlBr > ttlBrTm830 Then
                    Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 5263615
                End If
            ElseIf stfTm > StfTm900 Then
                If ttlBr > ttlBrTm900 Then
                    Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 5263615
                End If
            End If
        Next stfTm
    Next ttlBr
```

What am I missing?

[image]

EDIT: Picture added for clarity

Comment: try `stfTm.value`

Comment: Instead of using `Selection.FormatConditions`, use `ttlBr.FormatConditions` if that is the number you want to format.  Otherwise you are dependent on the location of the current cell selected.

Comment: What value do you have in columns T and H? Provide a sample please. `TimeValue` will set time, but date will be January 1 of the year 1.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I added .value in, but not change

Comment: try with Interior.ColorIndex

Comment: @DarrellH I tried this but it breaks the script giving a subscript out of range error (although your suggestion makes full sense)

Comment: @EganWolf the values in H vary from let's say 8:30:00 to 9:10:00, the values in T vary from let's say 00:30:00 to 01:30:00.  All are valid time values, no dates used

Comment: I might be missing it, but aren't you using `selection` without ever selecting anything. Should you swap `ttlBr` for  `selection`.

Comment: All, I added a picture above so you can see the sample values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the most important mistake is that you are doing **two nested loops**, whilch mean you are checking all cells of `T2:T7` versus all cells of `H2:H7`. What you actually need is to compare cells on the same row, right? Also you are setting the `FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color` after checking, which doesn't make sense. Either set some `FormatConditions` or use `Range.Interior.Color`, but don't mix them.

The *"subscript out of range"* error is most likely due to `FormatConditions(1)` which does not exist.

Try with format conditions something like this instead of the loops:

```
  With Sheet1.Range("T2:T7").FormatConditions
    .Delete
    .Add(xlExpression, , _
    "=AND(T2>" & ttlBrTm830 & ", H2 <" & StfTm900 & ",H2 >" & StfTm830 & ")").Interior.Color = 5263615
  End With
```

Comment: You are right, I want to compare the values in the same row.  I think I understand what you are saying.  The goal is so that if the person in the first row works between 8.5 and 9 hours but goes over break, I highlight the cell.  If they work 9 or more hours, but go over break (a different break value since they worked a "full" day), then that gets highlighted too.

How do I switch this around to compare correctly?

Comment: @sbagnato use the `FormatConditions` as indicated, and simply adjust that formula to what you need by applying it to cells `H2` and `T2`. The Format conditions will auto-fill accordingly to the other rows since you're not using absolut (`$`) references. You can also consideradding the CF and its formula by Excel'GUI instead of VBA.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
ttlBr.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 5263615
```

will only work if the cell already has a format condition, otherwise it throws the error described